# Issues with updating screen resolution on a headless pi using VNC

Tags: pi-4, screen

Updated my screen res to 1080p using `sudo raspi-config`. After a reboot, VNC is still showing it as the same old small box.

I have disabled overscan but can't really find any information on this issue.

How would I go about forcing an update to the screen resolution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspbian Buster **Screen Configuration utility** has a cunningly hidden **Configure/Screens/HDMI-1/Resolution** menu.

This seems to set the GUI resolution independently of the resolution set in Command Mode (at least on Pi4).

The good thing is that it can be changed in real time on a running Pi (at least on Pi4).
The bad thing is that it seems to set resolution, ignoring screen specific settings in `config.txt`.

I have not been able to find any documentation on this utility.
I just tried on a Pi3B+ and it isn't present, so it must be Pi4 only.

I haven't yet tried on VNC.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I was looking in the screen config tool but didn't manage to find anything.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I found the utility, but it won't show anything other than 640x480 and the VNC headless resolution is completely ignored.